# Continuous periodic functions not approximable by a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

What is an example of a continuous periodic function that is not the limit of any Fourier series? If not, is there an more or less elementary proof?

Comment: What makes you think there is one?  Have you looked at the theorem on the convergence of Fourier series?  What conditions can you violate?

Comment: Every periodic continuous function is the uniform limit of a sequence of Fourier series. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence) there is a continuous function whose Fourier series $\lim_{N\to \infty}\lim_{M\to \infty}\sum_{n=-M}^N c_n e^{i nx}$ diverges at $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part, there is some potential imprecision of language that confuses beginners here. I know it confused me. Plus, a surprising fact:

First, it has been known since at least since Fejer that every continuous function is a uniform-pointwise limit of finite Fourier series $\sum_{|m|\le N} c_{N,n} e^{2\pi inx}$.

More specifically, Fejer gave a formula for $c_{N,n}$ in terms of the Fourier coefficients $\widehat{f}(n)$ of the function $f$ itself...

The seeming paradox is that $c_{N,n}$ definitely *cannot* be $\widehat{f}(n)$ in general! That is, "the Fourier series" of $f$'s finite subsums are in general *not* the sequence of Fourier sums that converge uniformly to $f$. Crazy, seems to me.

Comment: Crazy, but it gives us something to do...